# Date Casting in Javascript

Tags: javascript, date

```
alert(new Date("8/14/2012 4:24:34 PM"));
Tue Aug 14 2012 16:24:34 GMT+0800 (Malay Peninsula Standard Time)


alert(new Date("14/08/2012 4:31:29 PM"));
Invalid Date
```

I tried date.parseExact from datejs, it doesn't work.

Is there any other way to cast "14/08/2012 4:31:29 PM" to a Date object?

Comment: "_I tried date.parseExact from datejs_" - what arguments did you use? Show use the code for this as well

Comment: date.parseExact("14/08/2012 4:31:29 PM", "dd/MM/yyyy h:mm:ss tt");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than Date.parseExact have you tried using Date.parse function provided by the datejs library like so

```
Date.parse("14/08/2012 4:31:29 PM")
```

Answer (score 4):

How about a quick swap using a regular expression?

```
alert(new Date("14/08/2012 4:31:29 PM".replace(/^(\d+)\/(\d+)/,'$2/$1')));
```

Comment: No problem. Basically, the code swaps the date and month numbers before passing it to `new Date()`.