# Is there a GraphQLObject or GraphQLAny type in GraphQL?

Tags: javascript, graphql

I am using GraphQL.

Right now there is a field in database from user. It is an Object, but can be any Object and have any level.

Is there something like `GraphQLObject` or `GraphQLAny` type? Thanks

```
const SomeType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'PrintSpec',
  fields: () => ({
    name: { type: GraphQLString },
    count: { type: GraphQLFloat },
    userData: { type: GraphQLWhatType },  // <- here how can I define this type?
  })
});
```

Comment: This question should help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45598812/graphql-blackbox-any-type

Comment: additionally, casting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11948667/date-casting-in-javascript

Comment: that may be   GraphQLList and the implimantation is in the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38666767/graphql-how-to-implement-a-graphqllist-of-graphqlobjecttypes